# How to scroll up the combobox list in VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, vbscript, combobox, automation

I am automating an application which is having a dropdown/combobox list. The item  which i want to select is not visible in the list, i need to scroll it up for making it visible.
Please suggest me how can i scroll the list of combobox in VBScript?

Comment: Sounds cool. Can you show us what you have? Is this an HTA with a `<select>` element?

Comment: <input name="ctl00$c$qe1$qfSrc$clauseValue2" title="[Any]" class="tswa-text-box" id="ctl00_c_qe1_qfSrc_clauseValue2_txt" style="width: 100%;" type="text" _events="[object Object]" autocomplete="off" value="[Any]"/>